How to get pagination works with Delphi and UniDac
I'm trying to make a UniDac Qurey uniqurey works with pagination but I couldn't figure out how?
I just want to load data by group as pagination do, how can I do that using uniDac table/qurey? I'm not looking for SQL statements but is there a way to it through the component itself like what is in fireDac?
I tried the FetchOptions.RecsMax := 2; but it doesn't seem working for me.
I found lots of fireDac stuff but nothing on uniDac!
I tried their help pages but still I didn't find anything maybe related or clear to me.
any help please for a reference of example?

Why don't you use SQL FETCH/LIMIT OFFSET, depending on your DMBS?

@fisi-pjm because simply my DB doesn't support it "I'm not looking after SQL statements" it's on my question :)

Have you Tried using the FetchRows property? Set that one to 2 (to match your example) and the FetchAll Property to false. then Execute the Query. When your Dataset courser move to the last Record (in your example 2) it should fetch another 2 Records.

@fisi-pjm Yes I did, the FetchAll Property is not there in the object inspector! but in code if u set it to like FetchingAll := false; it will give an error of "left side cannot be assigned to"
